Restrict specific webpage in iOS Universal Link
I have enabled deeplink for ios app but i would like to restrict "Specific Link" which invoke mobile app. I tried the below code but still app is launching from the url.
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "YOURTEAMID.your.bundle.identifier",
        "paths": [
          "*",
          "NOT /blocked-page",
          "NOT /private/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

So how can we restrict it?

Starting from iOS 13 the format has changed a bit.
The new format is this:
"applinks": {
  "details": [
    {
      "appIDs": [
        "ABCDE12345.com.example.app",
        "ABCDE12345.com.example.app2"
      ],
      "components": [
        {
          "#": "no_universal_links",
          "exclude": true,
          "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link. Like example.com/path?query=1234#no_universal_links"
        },
        {
          "/": "/buy/*",
          "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /buy/"
        },
        {
          "/": "/help/website/*",
          "exclude": true,
          "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/website/ and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
        },
        {
          "/": "/help/*",
          "?": {
            "articleNumber": "????"
          },
          "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /help/ and that has a query item with name 'articleNumber' and a value of exactly 4 characters"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Source
Note that after changing the contents of your AASA file, you need to wait until the Apple CDN has the updated version.
To check whether Apple CDN already has it, do a simple GET request with https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/YOURDOMAIN and check if the result matches your AASA file's latest state.

i tried above solution as well, still facing the same issue.

@ParmarDarshak as I mentioned, it takes time to reflect the changes on apple's CDN.
Did you check the current state of your aasa with the link I posted? https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/YOURDOMAIN
